# How to prevent an iframe from flickering when clicking an anchor link in WebKit?

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, webkit

In my web application I am using an `iframe` to embed content. The user can interact with the iframe using anchor links, which causes the content of the iframe to reload.

I notice that on WebKit (Chrome or Safari) the iframe "flickers", in particular on slow lines. Apparently the flicker is caused by clearing the iframe before the new content is loaded. This does not happen in other browsers under the same conditions, e.g. FF or IE. Also if I open the content of the iframe in a new, separate browser tab, the UI does not flicker in  this case, so the flickering seems indeed be caused by the iframe.

I posted an example here:
http://www.genprofi-stammbaum.net/test/iframes.html

Clicking the link in the iframe causes flicker on Chrome, the more if the line is throttled, e.g. using "Simulate Modem Speeds" in Fiddler.

The scenario is very straight forward, the main page is:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <iframe src="iframe-content.php">
 </iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

The content of the iframe is

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  a, a:visited {color: blue}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="<?php print "iframe-content.php?a=".time(); ?>">
<?php print "link_".time(); ?>
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way I can prevent WebKit from clearing the iframe before painting the content?

Comment: The same issue is also demonstrated on [http://jsfiddle.net/2tEVr/](http://jsfiddle.net/2tEVr/). Any comments to solve it are welcome!